# IllegalStateException when calling an Intent for the Alarm

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to set an alarm with an Intent, but when I try to open the Intent it crashes with an IllegalStateException.

Here's the code to open the Intent when a button is clicked:

```
public void guardarClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, descriptionAlarm.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, datePicker.getHour());
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, datePicker.getMinute());
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}
```

Here's the error:

```
04-12 20:01:19.288 4559-4559/edu.lasalle.pprog2.ac3_E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: edu.lasalle.pp2, PID: 4559
                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_ALARM cmp=com.android.deskclock/.HandleApiCalls (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{723e06e 4559:edu.lasalle.pprog2.ac3/u0a81} (pid=4559, uid=10081) requires com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3101)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
                                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                                            at edu.lasalle.pprog2.ac3.AlarmActivity.guardarClick(AlarmActivity.java:59)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should always post your stacktrace

Comment: @JeffersonTavares did it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should add permission  `com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
   ```
2. Use `startActivity(i)` instead of `startActivityForResult(i, 1)`.

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
   i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, descriptionAlarm.getText().toString());
   i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, datePicker.getHour());
   i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, datePicker.getMinute());
   startActivity(i);
   ```

Comment: @HessianMad My pleasure.... :) If my answer seems useful to you then please mark as accepted answer and give an up vote. Thanks in advance.